# Magento SQL - Copy all product names to short_description attribute

Tags: mysql, magento

I need to copy all Magento's product names to `short_description` attribute. I need to just insert the product names into the correct table but I'm not sure how.

Here is the SQL I use to get the all the product names:

```
SELECT `value` AS product_name
FROM `mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar`
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM mage_eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mage_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM mage_eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
```

The short_description `attribute_id` is 506:

```
SELECT * FROM `mage_eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 506
```

Comment: do u want to add the peroduct name as the `short_description` .?

Comment: Never fire SQL to magento db, this is the thumb rule, this is very alluring and bad practice.

Comment: When you poke Magento EAV with a SQL stick, it often comes back at you with a large spikey corrupted database club. Use collections or dataflow export/import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way magento needs to be used, use collections and write a script which would do that, I have scribbled the code below I am not sure if that will work but this is the best approach that comes to mind.:

```
<?php include "app/Mage.php";

     Mage::app();
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
               ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // select all attributes

     // we iterate through the list of products to get attribute values 
         foreach ($collection as $_product) {
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
           $product->setShortDescription($product->getName());
           $product->save();
        }  

?>
```

Comment: Much easier than sql anyway - thanks for the tip.. PS: You forgot a few ";" in your answer ;)

Comment: WC. Please update the answer with working code, that would be of great help. Did not have ide while writing the answer...

Comment: I spoke too soon.. the server keeps timing out.. tried updating server timeout settings in magento, php.ini & .htaccess but no luck.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just modifying Munjal's great answer to do it in smaller batches to avoid the server timeouts:

```
<?php include "app/Mage.php";

     Mage::app();
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
               ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // select all attributes
               ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                    'from' => 1,
                    'to' => 200
                ));

     // we iterate through the list of products to get attribute values 
         foreach ($collection as $_product) {
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
           $product->setShortDescription($product->getName());
           $product->save();
        }  

?>
```